# How to import path to php interpreter from docker container to $PATH Linux?

Tags: php, docker, atom-editor

It is possible? It need because editor Atom gives error "Error running PHP Error: Failed to spawn command `php`. Make sure `php` is installed and on your PATH".
And I don't want install PHP on my host machine.